# Не могу никак выровнять сетку

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Вот такая корявая сетка получилась [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотелось бы, чтобы буквы и цифры встали ровно, не понимаю, что не так? Пытаюсь, пытаюсь, ничего не получается

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:weightSum="100"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:paddingRight="50dp"
android:paddingLeft="50dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="50"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/characters"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/numbers"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:id="@+id/gameTablePlayer1"/>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="50">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:id="@+id/gameTablePlayer2"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**characters**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ru.albatros.buttleshit.TextViewSquare
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="А"/>

<ru.albatros.buttleshit.TextViewSquare
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="B"/>

<ru.albatros.buttleshit.TextViewSquare
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="C"/>

<ru.albatros.buttleshit.TextViewSquare
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="D"/>

<ru.albatros.buttleshit.TextViewSquare
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="E"/>

<ru.albatros.buttleshit.TextViewSquare
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="F"/>

<ru.albatros.buttleshit.TextViewSquare
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="G"/>

<ru.albatros.buttleshit.TextViewSquare
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="H"/>

<ru.albatros.buttleshit.TextViewSquare
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="I"/>

<ru.albatros.buttleshit.TextViewSquare
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="J"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**numbers**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ru.albatros.buttleshit.TextViewSquareX
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="1"/>

<ru.albatros.buttleshit.TextViewSquareX
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="2"/>

<ru.albatros.buttleshit.TextViewSquareX
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="3"/>

<ru.albatros.buttleshit.TextViewSquareX
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="4"/>

<ru.albatros.buttleshit.TextViewSquareX
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="5"/>

<ru.albatros.buttleshit.TextViewSquareX
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="6"/>

<ru.albatros.buttleshit.TextViewSquareX
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="7"/>

<ru.albatros.buttleshit.TextViewSquareX
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="8"/>

<ru.albatros.buttleshit.TextViewSquareX
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="9"/>

<ru.albatros.buttleshit.TextViewSquareX
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="10"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**TextViewSquare**

```
public class TextViewSquare extends TextView {

public TextViewSquare(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public TextViewSquare(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public TextViewSquare(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec); 
}
}
```

**TextViewSquareX**

```
public class TextViewSquareX extends TextView {

public TextViewSquareX(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public TextViewSquareX(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public TextViewSquareX(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec); 
}
}
```

Добавил пустой `TextView` перед буквой А, получилось вот что [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в вертикальный линеарлейаут нужно положить буквы и горизонтальный линеарлейаут , в котором цифры и поле, выровнять всё с помощью margin и padding. И weight это не проценты, не обязательно по 50 ставить, можно и по 1. http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/38-urok-7-layout-parametry-dlja-view-elementov.html

Comment: Паддинги / маргины не прокатят, у меня зависимости  от экранов заданы

Comment: Прикол в том, что я в `characters` и `numbers` растягиваю 10 `view`, соответственно столбик с цифрами тоже считается как часть и растягивается не по стороне сетки а по стороне сетки + ширина столбца с цифрами. Если делать маргин, то надо знать насколько, а я не знаю, т.к все зависит от экрана

Comment: Как же неудобно эти разметки делать

Comment: а вы не смотрели в сторону GridView? Если вы знаете размер своей ячейки, то ничего выравнивать не надо!

Comment: @Ivan Vovk, Я не знаю размер ячейки. `GridView` работает с 4.0 андроида

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот смотрите: берем сторону квадрата 40 например. Всем текствью ставим 40dp ширину и высоту и те же параметры ячейкам гридлейаута. Вот пример структуры лэйаута:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/letters_width"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/letters_width">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="2"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="3"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="@dimen/letters_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="a"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="b"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="c"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/letters_width"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/letters_width">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="2"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="3"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="@dimen/letters_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="a"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="b"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="c"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ListView нужно только поменять на Ваш ресайклервью, сделать нужное количество букв и цифр и подогнать размеры. Так же можно вместо дублирования воспользоваться   [Include](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/include.php)

Comment: Проблема в том, что 40dp не гарантирует правильные размеры. Нужно как то с весом справиться. Я даже с `RelativeLayoyt` это сделать не могу

Comment: Как раз `include` я использую

Comment: У меня ещё будет куча вью так что... Блин. Я сдаюсь. Сделаю конкурсом.

Comment: отредактировал с весом. @dimen/letters_width определяет ширину текствью с буквами и высоту с цифрами.

Comment: Вообщем, я завтра включу на полную мозг и сделаю. Я не могу указать конкретные размеры, вся игра будет без них, только вес